# CMake ignoring variable in custom command

Tags: linux, cmake

disclaimer: I'm a newbie.

I have the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8.10.2 )
project( widget  )

# gleaned from the original makefile
add_definitions( -DPJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 )
add_definitions( -DPJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 )
add_definitions( -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 )

SET ( SRC_PATH  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/pj )
SET ( sources ${SRC_PATH}/addr_resolv_sock.c 
          ${SRC_PATH}/file_access_unistd.c 
          ${SRC_PATH}/file_io_ansi.c 
          ${SRC_PATH}/guid_simple.c
          ${SRC_PATH}/log_writer_stdout.c
          ${SRC_PATH}/os_core_unix.c
          ${SRC_PATH}/os_error_unix.c
          ${SRC_PATH}/os_time_unix.c
          ${SRC_PATH}/os_timestamp_common.c
          ${SRC_PATH}/os_timestamp_posix.c
          ${SRC_PATH}/pool_policy_malloc.c
          ${SRC_PATH}/sock_bsd.c
          ${SRC_PATH}/sock_select.c 
          )

SET( outpath ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} "/lib/" )
message(" outpath = " ${outpath} )

include_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include )

add_library( pj ${sources} )

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND( TARGET pj POST_BUILD 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "what now?"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy libpj.a  "$outpath" 
    )
```

And for some reason, the value of `$outpath` in the copy command is ignored.  If I put in a hardcoded string, e.g., "bubba", it works.  If I set `$outpath` to "bubba" it does not work.

I have tried all known variations on `$outpath` -- `${outpath}`, `"$outpath"`, `"${outpath}"`...
but none work.

This has got to be something obvious (to you), but I cannot see it.
All help appreciated!

:bp:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is the value of `outpath`.  You should avoid leaving a space in the [`set`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aset) command, since this will interpret the value as two separate entries, the first being `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}` and the second being `/lib/`.

The other issue is simply in the use of [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command).  You should favour using "generator expressions" here.  From the docs:

> Arguments to COMMAND may use "generator expressions" with the syntax "$<...>". Generator expressions are evaluated during build system generation to produce information specific to each build configuration.

Also, you need to create the "/lib" directory before calling `cmake -E copy` if the destination is a directory (which it is in this case).

Finally, a minor optimisation would be to make use of the `cmake -E copy_if_different` rather than `copy`.

So to summarise, you need to do something like:

```
set( outpath "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib" )
...
add_custom_command( TARGET pj POST_BUILD 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${outpath}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:pj> ${outpath}
)
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  I guess I'm too used to python or other language where strings are concatenated 'normally'...    Whew!

Comment: @BillyPilgrim No probs :-)

Answer (score -1):

Actually not a direct answer to the ignored variable problem, but maybe what you should be using is defining the CMake variables [LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#variable%3aLIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH) and [EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#variable%3aEXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH) or respective properties on individual targets if you want to define the output locations for targets.

Comment: Using generator expressions in the `COMMAND` argument of `add_custom_command` obviate this more complex approach.

Comment: SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH somewhere) looks actually much easier to me?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't give the full path to location of the built library for multi-configuration generators like MSVC or XCode, since these apply a per-configuration subdir to the path.  See e.g. docs for [`CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR) Trying to work round this issue without using generator expressions can be difficult, since for these IDEs, the build type isn't set via CMake.  Also, `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH` has been deprecated in favour of `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, and `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`